# How to check specific special character in String

Tags: java, regex

I am having below String value, in that how can I find the only this four specified special character like `[],:,{},-()` (square bracket, curly bracket, hyphen and colon) in a given String.

```
String str = "[1-10],{10-20},dhoni:kholi";
```

Kindly help me as I am new to Java.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html, try something and come back

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use regular expression like this.

```
class MyRegex
  {
     public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
     {
       String str = "[1-10],{10-20},dhoni:kholi";
       String text = str.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9]","");    // replacing all numbers and alphabets with ""
       System.out.print(text); // result string

     }

   }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only characters that you want to check then you can use String.replaceAll method with regular expression

```
System.out.println("[Hello {}:-,World]".replaceAll("[^\\]\\[:\\-{}]", ""));
```